# How to read and edit a list from disk in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, disk

I have a list of dictionaries that I want to append to a separate disk file. Then, I want to be able to read this list of dictionary items and move them to other lists, in different files.

```
import os

# List 'x' will auto-populate itself with hundreds of new dictionary items upon run - using x.append({'name': f'{var}', 'job': f'{var2}'}) etc.

x = []

i = input('Request: ')

if i == 'add to list':
    with open('example list', 'a') as list:
        list.write(x)
elif i == 'print list':
    with open('example list', 'r') as list:
        list.read(x)
        print(list)

# in this next block, I would like to be able to move an item from the 'example list' list to a different list that is housed in a separate file

elif i == 'move item':
    # 'n' requests an integer value to represent the index in the list
    n = input('Which item do you want to move? ')
    with open('example list', 'r') as list:
        j = list[n]
        # I want to delete 'j' from 'example list' 
    with open('other list', 'a') as other_list:
        # I want to append 'j' to 'other list'
        other_list.write(j)

print('example list')
```

I am stuck on reading and moving these list items. I can't even get it to print "example list" in a nice format.

I have heard of `pickle` module, but I've never used it. I also understand that it may be necessary to save these lists as json files in order to be able to access the list items and the subsequent dictionary keys within.

Comment: I'm not certain why you are doing so many I/O operations, but I would suggest this as an order of ops for the second part: Determine item to move, read list it will be removed from, remove item (look into `del`, `remove`, `pop` keywords), write this list back to its file in edited form, read in list the item will be added to in it's entirety, append item to list, write full list back to file by overwriting past version.

Comment: You have several fundamental misunderstanding, I think. You are simply writing the text representation of a list to a text file. When you read it, it will not be a list. Note, you are doing things like `with open('example list', 'r') as list:` but that doesn't magically convert whatever is in your file to a list, `list` will now be a file object, the name is irrelevant... Fundamentally, you are trying to *serialize* Python objects. You can use `pickle` for a binary format that works with arbitrary python objects, or maybe JSON, a text-based format would work here.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do the I/O operations?

Comment: Yes sorry maybe 'list' was a misleading variable name, haha. So how would you convert this to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Using the json module I was able to dump the list to an external json file with:

```
x = []

with open('json list.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(x, f)
```

I could then load the data back in with:

```
list1 = open('json list', 'r')
listread = list1.read()
data = json.loads(listread)
```

For moving items between lists I used this:

```
move_item = data[3]
del move_item
json.dumps(data)
move_to = open('other list'. 'a')
move_to.write(move_item)
list1.close()
move_to.close()
```

Once loaded, the list and subsequent dictionaries within remain intact as their respective objects, thus allowing for access via index or key. Thank you to everyone, I used a combo of everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconception here *as list* does not convert the content into a list. It's like a variable. I have changed some parts of your code. I dont know if it would work as you didn't specify any inputs or outputs. have a look

```
if i == 'add to list':
    with open('example list', 'a') as f:
        # append whatever there is in 'x' into 'example list'
        f.write(x)
elif i == 'print list':
    with open('example list', 'r') as f:
        file_content=f.read()
        print(file_content)

# in this next block, I would like to be able to move an item from the 'example list' list to a different list that is housed in a separate file

elif i == 'move item':
    # 'n' requests an integer value to represent the index in the list
    n = input('Which item do you want to move? ')
    with open('example list', 'r') as f:
        # .readlines() would return a list of lines from 'example list'
        file_lines = f.readlines()
        # pop line with index 'n'
        j = file_lines.pop(n)
        # I want to delete 'j' from 'example list' 
    with open('other list', 'a') as other_list:
        # I want to append 'j' to 'other list'
        other_list.write(j)

print('example list')
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me read and print the external file in a nice format. Now I will try your suggestions for moving the items, great ideas.

Comment: @MajorTonality good to hear that. if it helps please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion for the moving of the list item. Using 'pop' does seem to work if I use 'w' instead of 'r'. However I get this error message after running the pop function - io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: If I don't change from 'r' to 'w' the pop function does nothing.

Comment: Actually upon further inspection it appears that using the pop function is removing everything within the list, not just the requested index position.